# EF6 'Nested' DbContexts - could this cause problems

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following example which will illustrate my question:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserService.CreateUser("NewUser");
    }
}

public static class UserService
{
    public static void CreateUser(string userName)
    {
        // DB Context created to CREATE the new user
        using (var db = new TestEntities())
        {
            User userToAdd = new User();
            userToAdd.name = userName;
            userToAdd.jobTitle = JobService.LookupJob(userName);
            db.Users.Add(userToAdd);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public static class JobService
{
    public static string LookupJob(string userName)
    {
        // 'nested' using, which opens up a new connection to 'read'
        using (var db = new TestEntities())
        {
            return db.JobTitlesNames.Single(a => a.userName = userName).title;
        }
    }
}

public class TestEntities : DbContext
{

}
}
```

This is a very noddy example of a scenario I have on a bigger scale. I guess my question is: can this method of 'nested' DbContext creations cause application/sql problems in a large scale application. I know that this sort of structure is bad practice, and generally you should use the same DbContext per business transaction ( in this case, the business transaction being creating a new user ), but if the 'nested' DbContext is only used to read data, never modify, is it still dangerous?

The real-world system I have uses this sort of structure massively, occasionally going down to 4-5 levels of nesting. I'm having ( not going to cover it in detail here, this question is more around theory ) database read/commit problems and I'm wondering if this could be the route cause.

Thanks